# Laravel posts of the user in one column, separated in rows and the user name in the first line in the same column

Tags: laravel, foreach

I have two tables

users

- id
- name

posts

- id
- name
- user_id

All posts should be in the same column of the owner user of these posts, but the foreach in laravel print just in rows and cant thinks any way to do in this way.

The code is:

```
<?php 

$search = \App\Post::all()->groupBy('user_id');
$total_users = \App\User::count();
$total_posts = 0;
```

?>

```
    <table>
     <tbody>

     @foreach($search as $user_id => $posts)
       @if ($loop->first)
         <tr>
       @endif
    
         <td>            
           {{ $posts[0]->user->name }}
           <?php $total_posts += $posts->count();  ?>
         </td>
    
      @if ($loop->last)
        </tr>
      @endif

    @endforeach

    @for($c = 0; $c < floor($total_posts/$total_users); $c++)

     <?php
        $users_done = 0;
        $tr_done = false;
     ?>

    @foreach($search as $user_id => $posts)

      @if(isset($posts[$c]))
            
         @if ($loop->first)
            <tr>
         @endif
            
         <td>{{ $posts[$c]->name }}</td>                
                
         <?php
           $users_done++;
           $g++;
         ?>

         @if ($loop->last)
           <?php
              $tr_done = true;
           ?>               
           </tr>
         @endif
            
        @endif

     @endforeach  

     @if(!$tr_done)
        </tr>
     @endif

     @if($user_done>0 && $users_done<$total_users)
        
       @for($c = 0; $c < $total_users-$users_done; $c++)
          <tr><td></td></tr>
       @endfor
     @endif

     @endfor

    </tbody>
   </table>
```

I have 2k posts rows and i cant to print in this way!

Any help Please!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating table like this?

```
$table = [];
$users = 0;
$posts = 0;

foreach($users as $user){
    foreach($user->posts){
        $table[$posts][$users] = $post->name;
        $posts++;
    }
    $users++;
}
```